# Why can't a AES256-encrypted file be decrypted on machine other than the one it was encrypted?

Tags: aes, openssl

I encrypted a file on my mac using openssl

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -a -salt -in one.jpg -out two.jpg
```

now if I try to decrypt it like that:

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -a -d -salt -in two.jpg -out one.jpg
```

on my original machine, it works fine. But if I perform the same operation on another machine, it doesn't work. Why is that?

Comment: Could you provide the errors to us?

Comment: There are no errors, it executes fine. But I cannot open the decrypted file because it wasn't correctly written.

Comment: Does the output file have the expected size? Are its contents garbage, or is there anything recognizable?

Comment: Have you verified that you are truly trying to decrypt the same file on both sides by comparing 'md5sum one.jpg' and 'md5sum two.jpg'?

Comment: This should be a straightforward task; just replicated myself on Linux Mint Debian and OS X with no issues (files were identical).  It appears something is going wrong in your tool chain.  While my guess is its something benign; you may have a rootkit on one of your systems that replaced OpenSSL with something that say leaves a backdoor (but doesn't let encrypted files properly transmit).

Comment: You say you "cannot open the decrypted file". What *exactly* happens when you try?

Answer (score 2):

I just verified this by running the commands on a Debian Wheezy and an Ubuntu 10.04, I did not encounter any issues whatsoever, so I suspect that something might be wrong with the file itself. Make sure to check the integrity after transfer as suggested by [gowenfawr](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/3365/gowenfawr) in the comments.

You can check the integrity by running `md5sum` on both machines. This should yield the same values. If they don't then the files differ on byte level.

It might also be the [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) per suggestion in this [superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/383653/decode-file-encoded-on-one-system-using-openssl-on-another-system). But as said, it would be helpful to know your machines and openssl version.

Comment: That's not really an answer to his question.

Comment: How is it not an answer? As also suggested by other members the file might be corrupted during transfer which causes this behavior.

Comment: @Johnny It might not be a final answer, but it is helpful to determine the potential problem. Vote as you wish, but replicating the steps on another environment is generally helpful.